# How do I stop table data from breaking my layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a table of data that is being dumped from our database but because some of the information is extremely long it is breaking the layout of my page.

If one of the fields contains a string that makes the table wider than its container or even the screen then the table drops below my left-hand menu div.

If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS include this:

```
td, th {white-space:pre; overflow:scroll;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set an explicit width on the `table` and set the overflow either to `scroll` or `hidden` (on either the table, tr, or td depending what effect you need).